# undefined method `label' for nil:NilClass even though the rails association is set

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 2 tables:

1) Table archive with the column names id, shelfmark and harddisk_id

2) harddisk table with columns id, label

in app/models/archive.rb

```
class Archive < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :harddisk
end
```

in app/models/harddisk.rb

```
class Harddisk < ApplicationRecord
end
```

in views/archives/index.html.erb

```
  <% @archives.each do |archive| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= archive.shelfmark %></td>
      <td><%= archive.harddisk.label %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
```

What I am trying to achieve is to display the harddisk label through the harddisk table.

But I get an error:

> undefined method `label' for nil:NilClass

on

> <%= archive.harddisk.label %>

What am I doing wrong?

---

Update:

in Rails Console:

```
> foo = Archive.where(shelfmark:"foo")

> [#<Archive:0x007f916e1c21e8,
id:1,
shelfmark: 'foo'
harddisk_id: 1
]


  > foo.harddisk.label

NoMethodError: undefined method `harddisk' for #<Archive::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007f9170ea75c8>
```

Does it mean, that the Rails association isn't working? It seems to be unable to use on archive table the harddisk_id to retrieve the label from the harddisk table.

Comment: Well, that archive doesn't have a harddisk. What did you expect to happen here?

Comment: "Even though the harddisk_id is empty it shouldn't throw an error message, right?" - nope, I don't know why you'd think that :)

Comment: yeah, i confused it with a normal empty attribute in the table view. but I updated my post with a rails console where i tested it with an archive that has a harddisk.

Comment: Your console log is wrong. Your foo object is not an Archive. It’s a relation. The where method returns many archives. You cannot then use foo.harddisk.

Comment: @Trinity76: `foo = Archive.where(shelfmark:"foo").first.harddisk.label`

Comment: yes, you're right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Sergio pointed out in the comments, the error is occurring because some archives doesn't have a harddisk. 
So the dumb and simple way is to just prevent the exception from being raised and safely return a nil from the method call chain
`archive.harddisk.label` becomes `archive&.harddisk&.label` (Ruby 2.3 or later) or try() and if harddisk is nil, you get nil back, no exception

```
 <% @archives.each do |archive| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= archive.shelfmark %></td>
      <td><%= archive.harddisk.try(:label) %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
```